# Integrability of functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Briefly justify the following facts:

a) $|x|$ is integrable on $[-1,2]$

b) $x^{\frac{1}{4}}$ is integrable on $[0,9] $.

c) The function $h(x)=\begin{cases}
 x^2& x\in[0,1] \\
                      2x+3 &x\in(1,2]
\end{cases} \quad$
is integrable on $[0,3]$.

d) if $f, g$ are integrable on $[a,b]$ the so is $f-g$.

I would really appreciated if some one can give me at least directions how to to this? Thank you so much! And i am not sure should I just use theorems or I need to prove those things..

Comment: What facts do you have at your disposal?  Do you have that continuous functions are integrable?  Or that the composition of an integrable function with a continuous function is integrable?  Is linearity assumed?

Comment: Yes I have theorem that cts functions are integrable. Also I have a linearity theorem

Comment: Is there a typo in part (c)? Should that interval be $[1,2],$ rather than $[1,3]?$

Comment: No, there is no typo is part (c).

Comment: Your function isn't even *defined* on $[0,3],$ though. Should it be $(1,3]$ instead of $(1,2],$ perhaps?

Comment: I know that is not, It may be that is (1,3] but then it is my professor mistake..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a), (b), and (c) are just direct applications of the fact that continuous functions are integrable ((c) is piecewise continuous, from which we split the integral; more generally, there is a theorem that states that if the set of discontinuities of the function has measure zero and $f$ is bounded over a compact subset, then it is integrable over that subset). Also, in (c) there is the issue of the fact that the function is not defined over $(2,3]$, and thus the integral is not even well-defined.

(d) is true because of linearity; $\int_a^b{(f-g)d x}=\int_a^b{fdx} -\int_a^b{gdx}$.  Thus, since $\int_a^b{fdx}$ and $\int_a^b{gdx}$ are assumed to exist, $\int_a^b{(f-g)dx}$ exists and is equal to their difference.

Let me know if you want me to show the continuity/piece-wise continuity of the functions in (a), (b), (c).

Here is proof that (a) is continuous.  We write this as the piece-wise function $$|x|=\begin{cases} x & x\in (0,\infty) \\ -x & x\in(-\infty,0] \end{cases}.$$  On the interval $(0,\infty)$, it is clear that $|x|$ is continuous because $x$ is continuous (for each $\epsilon>0$ we choose $\delta=\epsilon$ to so that $|x-y|<\delta|$ implies $|x-y|<\epsilon$ for every $x\in (0,\infty)$.)  Similarly, on $(-\infty,0)$ it is continuous because $-x$ is continuous on this domain (proof similar to above).  Thus, it remains to see that $|x|$ is continuous at $x=0$.  It suffices to show that the limit from the right and left is equal $0$.  Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}{-x}=-\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}=-0=0=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}{x}$, we see that this is the case.  Thus, $|x|$ is continuous.

(b) is a rather ugly computation.

(c) is not continuous at $x=1$ because the left-hand limit is 1 and the right-hand limit is 5.  The integral is not defined, however, because we can't integrate over the region $(2,3]$ since $h$ isn't defined here.

Comment: The function in part (c) is *not* continuous, but it is bounded and continuous [almost everywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere).

Comment: Yes, I should have said piece-wise continuous.  I've also just realized it isn't even defined for the domain to be integrated over.

Comment: You can show for at least one of (a),(b),(c) and then I should figure out the rest

Comment: I am confused now, I would like you to show the rest of problem

Comment: Can you show the part (c) also?

Comment: As (c) stands in the given problem, there isn't much to show, since the integral does not exist.

Comment: @Mica: I recommend that you assume that there is a typo, make a correction using one of the two suggestions I made, and point out that you made the correction. Then, proceed to explain why the corrected version is Riemann integrable. What definition(s) of Riemann integrability do you know?

Comment: A function is Riemann integrable over a compact interval if, and only if, it's bounded and continuous almost everywhere on this interval

Comment: @Mica, corrected that.